# React Ios safari Mobile Web input focus keyboard doesn't come up

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobile, react-hooks, safari

We are developing with React + Typescript.

Currently, what I want to implement is when the page is rendered, I want to give focus to the input and bring up the keypad used on mobile.

But the focus works fine but the keypad doesn't come up.

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { css } from '@emotion/react';

import Container from '../../components/layout/Container';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');

  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Container footerElement={<Button label='확인' onClick={nextStep} />}>
          <input
            value={phoneNumber}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setPhoneNumber(event.target.value);
            }}
            ref={inputRef}
            type='tel'
            maxLength={11}
          />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: Getting the same with a similar component. You are not alone <3